# Turning a Python list of objects into a list of one-to-many objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary, one-to-many

Say we have a list of book objects, each with a title and an author ID:

```
books = [
    { 'title': 'book1', 'author_id': 'author1' },
    { 'title': 'book2', 'author_id': 'author2' },
    { 'title': 'book3', 'author_id': 'author1' }
]
```

How would we efficiently go about transforming this list into a list of author objects, with a books property containing all of that author's books? i.e., turn that list into this list:

```
authors = [
    { 'author_id': 'author1', 'books': [{ 'title': 'book1' }, { 'title': 'book3' }],
    { 'author_id': 'author2', 'books': [{ 'title': 'book2' }]
]
```

Here is my attempt at the solution, though it seems inefficient and convoluted:

```
authors = []

for book in books:
    # Index of the author's object if it has already been added to the array
    existing_author_indices = [i for i in range(len(authors)) if authors[i]['author_id'] == book['author_id']]

    # The author is already in authors, so add the book to its books
    if len(existing_author_indices) > 0:
        authors[existing_author_indices[0]]['books'].append(book)
    # Add the author to authors with this book as the only one yet
    else:
        author = { 'author_id': book['author_id'], 'books': [book] }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it important to keep the order of the books? If not wouldn't it be preferable to have the final result a dictionary of {author:books} pairs? Then you could index the database by author instead of having to look up `authors[i]['author_id']` when searching for the books of a specific author, instead you would just do `authors[desired_author]` to get the books by a specific author.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a dictionary is the best way to go. If I want to maintain the order I can always just use an `ordereddict`

Comment: well then take a look at your answers,  **every single one uses an authors mapping like this** as an intermediate step to get your original desired result.

Comment: Thanks. I have scrolled down and read the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), you can do:

```
key = lambda d: d['author_id']

authors = [
    {'author_id': k, 'books': [{'title': d['title']} for d in g]}
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(books, key=key), key=key)
]
```

This sorts and groups the book dicts by author_id (`k`) and accumulates the book titles for each group (`g`).

Btw, would the following structure not be a lot simpler without losing information:

```
authors = {
    k: [d['title'] for d in g]
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(books, key=key), key=key)
}

# {
#     'author1': ['book1', 'book3'],
#     'author2': ['book2']
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to generate a dictionary where keys are author names and values are list of books by each author. Once you have that it's easy to convert to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

books = [
    { 'title': 'book1', 'author_id': 'author1' },
    { 'title': 'book2', 'author_id': 'author2' },
    { 'title': 'book3', 'author_id': 'author1' }
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for book in books:
    d[book['author_id']].append({'title': book['title']})

[{'author_id': k, 'books': v} for k, v in d.items()] # [{'author_id': 'author1', 'books': [{'title': 'book1'}, {'title': 'book3'}]}, {'author_id': 'author2', 'books': [{'title': 'book2'}]}]
```

This would result to **O(n)** time complexity since it doesn't require sorting.

Comment: This may just be personal preference, but I'd just do `d[book['author_id']].append(book['title'])` and move the inner dictionary creation to the last step. That way, `d` is the underlying data structure, and the final step transforms it into the required format.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky That would work as well, I went with my approach since list comprehension within list comprehension would look more complex.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this (edit to how you see fit, I only did the titles)

```
{'author1': ['book1', 'book3'], 'author2': ['book2']}
```

You can get it like so

```
authors = dict()
for book in books:
    author_id = book['author_id']
    if author_id not in authors:
        authors[author_id] = list()
    author_books = authors[author_id]
    book_title = book['title']
    if book_title not in author_books:
        author_books.append(book_title)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, just collecting authors in a dict and finally return the constructed list:

```
def trans(books):
    authors = {}
    for bk in books:
        if bk['author_id'] not in authors:
            authors[bk['author_id']] = [{'title': bk['title']}]
        else:
            authors[bk['author_id']].append({'title': bk['title']})

    return [{'author_id': k, 'books': authors[k]} for k in authors]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Without multiple loops using a map

```
authors_map = {}
authors = []
for index, book in enumerate(books):
    if book['author_id'] in authors_map:
        authors[authors_map[book['author_id']]][
            'books'].append({'title': book['title']})
    else:
        authors_map[book['author_id']] = len(authors)
        authors.append({'author_id': book['author_id'], 'books': [
                       {'title': book['title']}]})
```